# What is the relation between Robot framework and Selenium framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

For web application automation Selenium can be used with Robot framework. But both are frameworks.What is the relation between these two?

Comment: Even though I think the answers provided are spot on for the question, I do think the question itself is too broad for stackoverflow. In addition I believe that this question could have (easily) been answered by reading the material on robotframework.org and seleniumhq.org. There is a certain level of effort that is expected to have been spent on preventing a question which I suspect was not spent here.

Comment: I partially disagree with the given answers, selenium is an interface to the webdriver API.

Comment: Okay sure Will look into it next time Kootstra!

Answer (score 8):

You have selenium to automate all the web related work e.g login,click,button and many more thing. But then you have to use it with some languages , e.g. Java ,Ruby, Python.

Suppose you get a project to automate a webbrowser by using any other languages , where your task would be

1)login to browser

2)Fill user details

3)Click on submit

Now to have a good framework , you need to break down these tasks into smaller component

1) you need to define test cases

2) You need to have a separate file to store variables

3) You need to have a good reporting tool , which will show how many test cases passed or failed and further drill down.

i am a python user,so lets talk the problem with python,selenium

1) you can write the test cases with unittest module - But then generating a good test reports would be hedache , you have to spend a lot of time to create good test reports

this is one of the major disadvantage with python

**Now coming to RobotFramework**

if you integrate selenium library in robotframe work, you would be able to do almost similar thing which can be done by any other languages with lot of ease and control.

Taking example of  your assignment in hand

1) You  can define Test cases

2) You can Create a seprate variable file and then pass it with main file during run time (check pybot -V)

3)You dont need to be worry about reporting part , all the reports would be generated and with betterdrill down options

**additional advantage**

1) There are lots of inbuilt libraries, which will help you to do your task easily

2) You can create your own custom library and import in Robotframework

3) You would be able to drill down till last variable where the problem is with help of RobotFramework Reports, which will save lots of time

In Nutshell i can say Robotframework provide a building block to your framework where you just need to worry about the functional aspect of your program

Comment: Than you so much. Such a detailed explanation made me to understand everything clearly.

Comment: @Vediccracker Consider accepting an answer that worked for you so that it helps others.

Answer (score 8):

Your original assertion is incorrect. They are not both frameworks. Or at least not the same type of framework.

**robot framework** is a set of programs and libraries for creating test cases. With it you can create test suites built upon reusable keywords written either from other keywords or written in other programming languages. The framework provides a test runner, and generates test reports.

**selenium** is a library interface to a driver that controls a browser. You cannot write tests using only selenium -- you need something else such as a programming language (python, ruby, etc) or testing framework (robot, cucumber, etc). Selenium itself provides no way to run tests, and no way to generate reports.